# Generating sas token through azure cli max limit reached

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to generate sas token through azure cli as show below

```
az storage container generate-sas --account-name aa--name etcd-backup --permissions acdlrw --expiry $expirydate --account-key xxx --https-only
```

When executing the below bash command from bash and trying to upload a file greater than 256 mb i am getting the below error

```
url -X PUT -T $ss_backup_file -H "x-ms-date: $(date -u)" -H "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob" "https://$storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/$sa_container/Nebula/$ss_backup_file_name?$sas_token"

<Error><Code>RequestBodyTooLarge</Code><Message>The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit
Time:2021-04-14T10:27:32.0287434Z</Message><MaxLimit>268435456</MaxLimit></Error>
```

Comment: Can you check the value of `sv` parameter in your SAS token and share it's value here?

Comment: @GauravMantri the value of SP is 2018-11-09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're encountering the restriction imposed by Azure Blob Storage Service. For Storage Service REST API version 2016-05-31 through version 2019-07-07, the maximum size of data that can be sent via [`Put Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) request is 256 MB. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob#remarks.

One possible solution is to make use of [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) and [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list) operations to split your large file into smaller chunks and then upload those chunks.

Another option is to make use of a Storage SDK to generate SAS token. When creating a SAS token, you can specify the Storage Service REST API version as a parameter. Then you should be able to specify a newer version (e.g. 2019-12-12 and later) which allows you to transfer larger files through `Put Blob` request. I was actually surprised to see it not being there in `az storage container generate-sas`.

Comment: How do i specify the Storage Service REST API version as a parameter can you give me an example

Comment: Not through CLI unfortunately. It is not exposed there. It is also not available in Azure PowerShell as well (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontainersastoken?view=azps-5.8.0). You will need to use one of the Storage SDKs (.Net, Python, Node etc.).

Comment: do you have any code using put block to upload file using bash?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Sorry!